# Problem installing usbip on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, usb, kernel

I am trying to set up USB/IP to share a USB device I have connected to my Pi model B.

Here are the steps I have completed.

I have installed the `usbip` package and cross-compiled a new kernel (`4.0.6-v7+`) on a Ubuntu (x86) VM with USBIP enabled.

I ran `usbipd -D` to start the daemon.

Then I listed the devices using `usbip list -l` and found the device is `1-1.3:1.0`.

When I mount it using `usbip --debug bind -b 1-1.3:1.0` I get this output:

```
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command] running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:143:[unbind_other] problem getting device attributes: No such file or directory
usbip: error: could not unbind driver from device on busid 1-1.3:1.0
```

---

Additional Info:

`uname -a` output: `Linux raspberrypi 4.0.6-v7+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 28 01:30:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: If more information is needed, please just ask.

Comment: what kind of device you using ? Do you use sudo while binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you trying to use a multifunction USB device. `usbip bind` wants the bus id instead of an exact device address. Because of that, the correct bind call in your case should look like this:

```
sudo usbip --debug bind 1-1.3
```